# How to handle a new question which is duplicate of existing unanswered question?

Tags: discussion, exact-duplicates

We can close a question as duplicate. But what if exsiting question is unanswered, should both the questions be kept open? If so, what's the point because if existing is unanswered then, new one also would be unanswered and it will increase unanswered percentage statistics only. For example,

New: [Does BIBI Nanchari has any scriptural evidence?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/29364/does-bibi-nanchari-has-any-scriptural-evidence)

Existing: [Was Lord Venkateshwara's second wife Bibi Nanchari really a Muslim?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/5360/was-lord-venkateshwaras-second-wife-bibi-nanchari-really-a-muslim)

Comment: If they can have potentially same answer i.e answer to one can work for another also, then I think they can be closed as duplicate.

Answer (score 7):

Generally it depends on interpretation of users whether two questions are duplicates or not, unless they are [accidental or copy paste duplicates](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/04/29/handling-duplicate-questions/). So, i think it really depends on interpretation of users here for the two questions on Bibi Nanchari.

But for unanswered duplicates, you can flag one question for moderation attention explaining reasons if you are very sure. [This meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10844/) post says:

> **Unanswered duplicates**: Generally, a question cannot be closed as a duplicate of an unanswered question, unless:
>
> - the site is a meta site
> - the questions were posted by the same user
> - a moderator closes the question
>
> The main point of closing questions as duplicates is to point users to
>   better answers; closing a question as a duplicate of an unanswered
>   question defeats this purpose. Also, this reduces the risk that
>   question A is closed as a duplicate of question B even though the
>   particular circumstances of question A allow an answer that wouldn't
>   work for B. If you're convinced that two unanswered questions are
>   duplicates, flag one for moderator attention and explain your
>   reasoning.

Comment: Just to understand..if i flag the new Q mentioned in my post...will this be closed...i mean is the above case mentioned in Q comes under the category to flag...?

Comment: @YDS If it is ambiguous, mods may discuss and decide.